# AngularJS Filter Sorting map (key,value) list

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I am trying to sort a list that I have

```
  {
    Student: 100,
    Student1: 60,
    Student2: 90,
  }
```

I am using a table and I need to sort the by their value. It currently sorts by the keys

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in ctrl.students" >

           <td >{{key}}</td>
            <td >{{value}}</td>

   </tr>
```

I am not sure how to add filtering to make sure it outputs the student scores from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you create an array of students with student name and student grade. And you loop through the students array by using `ng-repeat` and display individual student in descending order by grade. [AngularJS orderBy example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). The link is an example that using `ng-repeat` with `orderBy`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in ctrl.students | orderBy: '-grade' " >
  <td>{{student.name}}</td>
  <td>{{student.grade}}</td>
</tr>
```

Manipulate data so that it can be use for sorting:

```
$scope.students = [];
// someData is the data you received from database.
angular.forEach(someData, function(value, key){
  $scope.students.push({
    name: key,
    grade: value
  });
});
```

And after manipulation, your students array will look like this:

```
$scope.students = [
 {name: student, grade: 100}, 
 {name: student1, grade: 60}, 
 {name: student2, grade: 90} 
]
```

Comment: @user3100209 key and value just temperately variable you created so that you use in the template. You can name them whatever you want.

Comment: I cannot reorganize the array because I am pulling it from a database

Comment: Then you need to do some data manipulation after you receive the data from the database.

Comment: I am not familiar with javascript so not sure how to manipulate it... Would be able to send me a helpful link or something